# Pseudo-random number generator & password generator

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, random, rust

I've started learning Rust and decided to implement something on my own from scratch. I've implemented a PRNG and I use it to generate random passwords.

Project tree:

```
|   .gitignore
|   Cargo.lock
|   Cargo.toml
|
+---src
|       main.rs
|       password.rs
|       xorshift.rs
|
```

**main.rs** :

```
use std::io;

mod xorshift;
mod password;

fn main() {

    let length : u32;

    loop{
        let mut pass_leng_str = String::new();

        println!("Enter the length of wannable password: ");

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut pass_leng_str)
            .expect("Faild to read the line");

        let pass_leng_str = pass_leng_str.trim();

        match pass_leng_str.parse::<u32>(){
            Ok(i) => {
                length = i;
                break;
            },
            Err(..) => {
                println!("Not a valid integer!"); 
            },
        }
    }
    println!("Enter the characters you want to exclude: ");

    let mut exclude = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut exclude)
        .expect("Faild to read the line");
    
    let excluded : Vec<char> = exclude.chars().collect();

    println!("{}", password::rand_pass(length, excluded));

}
```

**password.rs** :

```
use super::xorshift;

pub static ASCII : [char; 69] = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 
    'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
    'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 
    'z', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y',
    'Z',
    '1','2','3','4',
    '5','6','7','8',
    '9','0',
    '+','-','_','?','!','$','/',
];

pub fn rand_pass(pass_len : u32, excluded : Vec<char>)-> String{
    let mut  password = String::new();
    for _i in 0..pass_len{
        let c : char = loop{
            let c = ASCII[xorshift::get_rand(69) as usize];
            if !excluded.contains(&c){
                break c
            }
        };
        password.push(c);
    }

    password
}
```

**xorshift.rs** :

```
use std::time::UNIX_EPOCH;
use std::time::SystemTime;

pub fn get_rand(len : u128) -> u128{
    let now = SystemTime::now();
    let from_unix = now.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).expect("Congrats on time travel!");
    let seed = from_unix.as_nanos();
    let x = seed;
    let x = x ^ seed << 13;
    let x = x ^ x >>17;
    let x = x ^ x <<5;
    let x = x % len;
    x as u128
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Rust, and welcome to Code Review!

## `rustfmt` & `clippy`

Always run `cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy` first.  [`cargo fmt`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt)
formats your code according to the official [Rust Style Guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/style-guide/README.md), and
[`cargo clippy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) detects common mistakes and provides feedback on
improving your code (none in this case).

## `main.rs`

The biggest problem with the `main` function is its structure.
Logically, the job of `main` is to:

- read the length of the password;
- read the excluded characters; and
- output the generated password.

You spent so much code on the first step that it is hard to recognize
at a glance without being familiar with input loops.  For readability,
it is preferable to extract all of this into a function:

```rust
fn input_length() -> usize {
    loop {
        eprintln!("Enter the length of password: ");

        let mut length = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut length)
            .expect("cannot read line");

        match length.trim().parse() {
            Ok(length) => return length,
            Err(_) => eprintln!("Error: invalid length\n"),
        }
    }
}
```

Lengths are usually represented by `usize` in Rust to avoid type
casts, instead of `u32`.

It is recommended to define variables as close to their usage as
possible.

Personally, I would change all occurrences of `println!` to
`eprintln!` expect the one that actually prints the password, so that
the program can be easily used in an automated script by reading
`stdout`.

Moving on, we see that there is no need to extract all characters in
`exclude`, a `String`, into `excluded`, a `Vec<char>` (the naming can
be improved, by the way).  A `String` encodes the characters in UTF-8,
which is variable-length, so ASCII characters take up only 1 byte
each, whereas a sequence of `char`s always stores each character as 4
bytes.  Moreover, UTF-8 is specially constructed so that searching
requires only a linear scan and no computation of character
boundaries, so there is no performance gain.

## `password.rs`

It shouldn't be the job of the `password` module to expose a constant
array containing ASCII characters.  A better name for `ASCII` may be
`ALLOWED_CHARS`.

The function `rand_pass` will often be called with the `password::`
prefix, so it is not necessary to repeat this information.  I would
name it `generate`.

Since the function does not consume `excluded`, take a `&[char]`, or
better, `&str` parameter.  See [Why is it discouraged to accept a
reference to a `String` (`&String`), `Vec` (`&Vec`), or `Box` (`&Box`)
as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219).

The function can be rewritten in a more logically straightforward
manner using iterators:

```rust
use std::iter;

pub fn generate(length: usize, excluded: &str) -> String {
    iter::repeat_with(generate_char)
        .filter(|c| !excluded.contains(&c))
        .take(length)
        .collect()
}
```

where `generate_char` is a function `Fn() -> char` that generates an
individual random character in the password, omitted for simplicity.
The intent is now clearer.

## `xorshift.rs`

A better name for the module might be `time_rng`.

`use` declarations can be condensed:

```rust
use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};
```

A mutable variable is more readable to me here:

```rust
let mut x = seed;
x ^= (seed << 13);
x ^= (x >> 17);
x ^= (x << 5);
x % len
```

It is best to not count on the reader knowing the operator precedence
here.